# Unable to set Checkbox to Checked after refreshing and storing in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I am currently facing an issue where I am unable to set a input box to stay checked after a refresh. I have stored the values in the local storage, even though the value is stored in the local storage; the checkbox does not remain checked. Please do help me on this! Thank you

Here is the html code:

```
      <div style="color: #005e95">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFullDownload" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _test" style="cursor: pointer;"  >
        Full Download
      </div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
_test: function(){
        let checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxFullDownload")

        if(localStorage.getItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`) === "AllowFullDownload"){
          checkBox.setAttribute("checked",true)
          console.log("set to true")
        }

        if(checkBox.checked){
          console.log("Checked")
          localStorage.setItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`,"AllowFullDownload")
          checkBox.checked = true;
          }
  
        if(!checkBox.checked){
          console.log("Unchecked")
          localStorage.removeItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`)
          checkBox.setAttribute("checked",false)
          }
}
```

Comment: try with `checkBox.checked = true` instead of (or as well as) `checkBox.setAttribute("checked",true)` - because `setAttribute` does not affect the `checkBox.checked` state - I'm also assuming `_test` runs on page load of course

Comment: if you want to control the state of the UI after refresh, maybe you should call a function when the event DOMContentLoaded gets fired (the DOM is loaded) that will set the state of that input to checked according to your conditions. setAttribute will work correctly .. that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **check** the checkbox on pageload then `localStorage.getItem()` must be out of scope of any functions which are executed on certain events.

```
 let checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxFullDownload");
_test: function() {
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Checked");
    localStorage.setItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`, "AllowFullDownload");
    checkBox.checked = true;
  }

  if (!checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Unchecked");
    localStorage.removeItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`);
    checkBox.checked = false;
  }
}
if (localStorage.getItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${_test.item._id}`) === "AllowFullDownload") {
    checkBox.checked = true;
    console.log("set to true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `checkBox.setAttribute("checked",true)` with `checkBox.checked = true`